# Pivot and concat dataframe values into a new column

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi The situation is quite simple but it will be easier to explain it with examples.

The data

[image]

The result I want to achieve
[image]

As you can see for each ID, I summarised all the categories they did in the new column `ALL_CATEGORY`

I guess I can use loop to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use groupby and create a new dataframe and then combine with the main dataframe. See example below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cat':["Delivery" ,"Gardending", "cleaning","Delivery","Marketing"],'id':[ 2, 2,2,3,3]})
df1.head()
```

results in

```
      cat       id
0   Delivery    2
1   Gardending  2
2   cleaning    2
3   Delivery    3
4   Marketing   3
```

then create this

```
   all_cat = df1.groupby('id')['cat'].apply(lambda x: pd.unique(x.values)).rename("All_cat").reset_index()
   all_cat.head()
```

will result in

```
id  All_cat
0   2   [Delivery, Gardending, cleaning]
1   3   [Delivery, Marketing]
```

then merge these two dataframes with

```
df2 = df1.merge(all_cat)
df2.head()
```

will result in

```
cat     id  All_cat
0   Delivery    2   [Delivery, Gardending, cleaning]
1   Gardending  2   [Delivery, Gardending, cleaning]
2   cleaning    2   [Delivery, Gardending, cleaning]
3   Delivery    3   [Delivery, Marketing]
4   Marketing   3   [Delivery, Marketing]
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to keep all other columns as well (INDEX, TASK_COMPLETED, CATEGORY, LOCATION), if I use groupby it seems I will lost all these. Is that possible to make ID and CATEGORY as dictionary key and values. Then use loop to extend values if the key is the same.

Comment: it shoud work with all other fields. I didn't put all of them in df1 just for convenience.